# Why css background image blink in chrome webview (android4.4.4)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Code purpose: Emulating a loading progress.

I use these code to change the position of the background image,
and found a bug that the background image blink in chrome WebView(android 4.4.4).

Please help to explain the rootcause and help to give a robust solution.

```
var x = 0,
    btnDom = document.getElementById('btnEle');

setInterval(function(){
    x++;
    btnDom.style.background = x + 'px 0px url(bg.png)';
}, 300);
```